# Getting average rate in ngb-rating module

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to keep average rates of all ratings in my Angular component but I have no clue about how to do that. I am looking into Angular with Bootstrap documentation but it is not helpful really.

Here is template rating.ts file:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-rating-template',
  templateUrl: './rating-template.html',
  styles: [`
    .star {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      color: #b0c4de;
    }
    .filled {
      color: #1e90ff;
    }
    .bad {
      color: #deb0b0;
    }
    .filled.bad {
      color: #ff1e1e;
    }
  `]
})
export class NgbdRatingTemplate {
  average = 0;
  count = 0;
  currentRate = 6;

  avg() {
    this.average = (this.average*this.count + this.currentRate) / (this.count + 1);
    this.count += 1;
  }
}
```

and also HTML file:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate" (rateChange)="avg()">
  <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
    <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100" [class.bad]="index < 3">&#9733;</span>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-rating>
<hr>
<pre>Rate: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>
<div> {{average}} </div>
```

But this is not what I want exactly because it only works for rate changes.

I need your advices, I don't have to use ngb-rating module btw, if you have better ideas about rating, I will be glad to learn those.

Comment: Can you provide a specific working example in a stackblitz? Just trying to understand exactly what you want to accomplish

Comment: https://skckh3.run.stackblitz.io